# BigQuery External Data Source Query Quotas

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a BigQuery table set up with a Cloud BigTable external data source.  This works fine, and I'm able to run queries joining my BigTable data to some of my other BigQuery data.  However, when I run too many queries against this table simultaneously, I get the following error:

> Error encountered during job execution:
>   Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries that read Cloud Bigtable data sources for this project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

I can't find any documentation about the limits on concurrent queries on the linked page or on the BigQuery Quotas and Limits page.  I'm not running that many queries here - max 10 at a time.  Has anyone run into this before who knows what the actual concurrent query limit is?

edit:

So people don't have to dig through the attached Google ticket, the correct answer (as of April 2018) is 4 concurrent queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather look for [`Quotas & Limits for Query Jobs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs)

> The following limits apply to query jobs created automatically by running interactive queries and to jobs submitted programmatically using jobs.query and query-type jobs.insert method calls.
>
> Concurrent rate limit for on-demand, interactive queries — 50 concurrent queries
>   Queries with results that are returned from the query cache, and dry run queries do not count against this limit. You can specify a dry run query using the --dry_run flag or by setting the dryRun property in a query job.
>
> Concurrent rate limit for queries that contain user-defined functions (UDFs) — 6 concurrent queries
>   The concurrent rate limit for queries that contain UDFs includes both interactive and batch queries. Interactive queries that contain UDFs also count toward the concurrent rate limit for interactive queries.

you cn find more in provided link

Comment: Do queries against an externally-sourced BigQuery table then count as containing UDFs?  It does make sense that my limit would be 6 based on what I was seeing, but I didn't see any information about that in the documentation.

Comment: cannot say for sure - but it's very likely having similar limits because of nature of underlying activity

Comment: That's actually a really interesting question! The docs say: _"you can run a query against the table as if it were a native BigQuery table, subject to the limits on external data sources"_ (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable). If you follow the link (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_quotas), it then says: _"The limits for external data sources are the same as the limits for load jobs, as described in the Load jobs section on the Quota Policy page."_. No mention of UDFs. Load job limit!? Let's get some Googlers onto this ;-)

Comment: @HerbertLee  - I think you should un-accept the answer  - so we have more chances that someone else jumps and provide better answer. As Graham pointed - in addition to query jobs limits - there is a load jobs limits when you query external sources. Still - not clear exactly which limit conditions applied in your case. I feel it is more likely that query jobs limits  - but it is just my feeling - wold be great to know exactly

Comment: As far as I can tell (using BigQuery engineer powers) the limit is four concurrent queries over BigTable. I would suggest [filing a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) asking for clarification, though--StackOverflow is not where official documentation should be :)

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I just filed a ticket.  Also, isn't StackOverflow the official documentation store for everything? :D

Comment: For anyone else who finds this thread, [this is the ticket on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74889511).